# updateable false column is getting updated

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a `createdAt` column in my table which I don't want to get updated after first creation. Therefore I marked it `updatable=false` in its definition. However when I use hibernate's update method, it is getting updated. When I check the hibernate update query log, I see that createdAt field is not included in the update query, but it gets updated anyway. Here is the code I am using (I work with hibernate 4)

--EDIT--
I am using mysql as database and apparently mysql workbench add `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` property to timestamp column by default. After removing `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` update by hibernate issue is resolved.

Here is the column definition

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "createdAt", nullable = false, length = 19, updatable = false)
public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}
```

Here is the update method:

```
Session session = null;
try {
    session = currentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(user);
    commitTransactionOfGivenSession(session);
} catch (HibernateException exc) {
    logRollbackAndThrowHibernateException(exc, session);
} finally {
    closeSession(session);
}
```

Hibernate Log which does not include `createdAt` field

```
update
    example_schema.Users 
set
    lastLogin=?,
    lastNotifiedAt=?,
    userName=?,
    waitingSince=? 
where
    userId=?
```

Comment: What DBMS, and how is the column defined on the database? And are there any triggers on the table that would cause the column to be updated?

Comment: I am using mysql and field is defined as TIMESTAMP. Now I see that there is a default value which is auto generated by mysql "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP". I am trying to remove this but mysql seem to ignore my change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using mysql as database and apparently mysql workbench add `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` property to timestamp column by default. After removing `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` property, issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the usual problem, in which you annotated the property, instead of the field, or the opposite. If your class is not additional annotated, you should remain consistent, in which you either annotate only your getters (properties) or fields (class variables).

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` property from created_at column.

```
ALTER TABLE `DATABASE_NAME`.`TABLE_NAME` CHANGE `create_at` `create_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```